# Concatenar comilla doble al principio

Tags: excel, vba

estoy tratando de concatenar una comilla doble para indicar un rango en VBA de Excel pero me da error y no logro identificar lo.

```
Var1 = "K12"
Var2 = "K554"
Rango = Var1 & ":"& Var2
```

Al imprimirlo me da K12:K554

Pero quiero me salga esto ---> "K12:K554"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las comillas se escapan con... otras comillas

Por ejemplo, `MsgBox """"` te mostrará `"`. En esa expresión están las dos comillas que indican inicio y fin de la cadena, las comillas que quieres pintar y las comillas que las preceden para escaparlas.

En tu código sería

```
Const ComillasTexto As String = """"
Rango = ComillasTexto & Var1 & ":" & Var2 & ComillasTexto
```

También se puede usar `Chr(34)` para representar las comillas sin pensar en escapar nada

```
Const ComillasTexto As String = Chr(34)
Rango = ComillasTexto & Var1 & ":" & Var2 & ComillasTexto
```